# IETF application/x-www-form-urlencoded over application/json

Tags: json, api, http, oauth, form-data

I was going through [IETF-6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#ref-W3C.REC-html401-19991224) standards for Oauth and I noticed that all POST requests where done using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and nowhere was `application/json` used as ContentType for request body.

I could not find any reason as to why this is required over `application/json`.

So my question is why is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` favoured over `application/json`? Is it because `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` provide more security over `application/json` or is it more performant?

Answer (score 1):

> is it because application/x-www-form-urlencoded provide more security over application/json

No.

> or is it more performant.

No.

Probable reasons for why form-urlencoded payload is chosen over JSON:

- Remember that the OAuth 2 standard is drafted based on OAuth 1, which dates back to a time where JSON was less of a buzzword.
- oAuth payload is basically key/value data. JSON would give a lot more flexibility in terms of the allowance for complex data structures, but that might be both a blessing and a curse, since it would also require more validation and potentially more compute to parse.
- Last but not least; The oAuth response payload might as well match the format of the request payload, and since the oAuth request parameters are usually part of the HTTP Authorization header, they need to follow a certain format. See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html and  https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt

Comment: This is exactly what I thought because IETF-6749  was drafted in 2012, it could just be because it is kinda old.